# Azure DevOps pipeline building Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gnu-make

I'm trying to set up an Azure DevOps build pipeline for CI of a C project that is built using gnu make that eventually runs gcc to compile and link.

While I wasn't sure which task to add to the pipeline in order to build a Makefile project, I tried going with a simple Command Line Script task, where it simply executes 'make' in the proper directory.

The problem is in detecting whether the build failed. In the Command Line Script task, under "Advanced" section, there is only the "Fail on Standard Error" option. The description says that if anything is written to stderr, the task will fail.

So if there is a compile or link error, the task indeed fails, which is the desired behavior. However, gcc also writes all compilation warnings to stderr, and that also causes the task to fail as well, which is not what we want.

Not having "Fail on Standard Error" checked results in the build being marked as successful regardless of how many real errors there are.

When this same build was run as part of a Jenkins job, it was somehow able to correctly interpret gcc/make output and fail the build only if there were actual errors reported. Is there a way to replicate the same behavior in Azure pipelines? Short of fixing all warnings or redesigning the build process to not write anything to stderr and then use some other means to test whether the build was successful?

Comment: Is searching the word "error" in stderr an option?

Comment: It is an option, but I feel it would be a workaround. I can't believe there isn't an easy built-in way to detect success or failure of make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command Line Script task just runs the provided script as a shell script and checks its exit code (non-zero means error). The thing is that the exit code of a script is the exit code of last statement and by default (unless `-e` option is given) the shell will proceed regardless of errors, i.e.:

#### Failing command

Step contents:

```
make -f nonexisting.mk
```

Result:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/bc2da066-dd8a-432d-b15f-b9c2bf7a8e1f.sh
make: nonexisting.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'nonexisting.mk'.  Stop.
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
Finishing: Command Line Script
```

The `make` command failed returning exit code 2 and the task was marked as failure. Next tasks were skipped.

#### Failing command overwritten by next statement

Step contents:

```
make -f nonexisting.mk
echo Do whatever else
```

Result:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/0b2ceea2-2821-4866-83c7-5d37a832ffe5.sh
make: nonexisting.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'nonexisting.mk'.  Stop.
Do whatever else
Finishing: Command Line Script
```

`make` command failed, but shell proceeded to the next statement (`echo`) which was successful, hence the exit code was 0, no error was detected by the task and the pipeline executed successfully.

#### Enable shell to stop on errors

Step contents:

```
set -e
make -f nonexisting.mk
echo Do whatever else
```

Result:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7f6644d3-408c-4b5b-b4d3-1f544e8a80ec.sh
make: nonexisting.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'nonexisting.mk'.  Stop.
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
Finishing: Command Line Script
```

The shell was enabled to exit on any encountered error; when `make` command fails, the script is terminated, `echo` command is not executed and the exit code is the exit code of failed command. This gets detected again by the task and the pipeline is terminated.

BTW. This is the standard way Jenkins is running shell scripts, passing `-e` by default so it works on Jenkins without doing anything explicitly.

You may want to review your task script for commands that overwrite `make`'s exit code. Possibly `set -e` in the script should do the trick unless you want more sophisticated logic in the script itself.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!